# how to detect optic disc in retinal images using matlab

Tags: matlab

```
enter code here

% Finding mean for 49*49 sub images
meanmat=ones(209,209);
k=1;count=1;
[m n]=size(BW);
for i=25:1:m-24
for j=25:1:n-24
rowst=i-24;rowend=i+24;
colst=j-24;
colend=j+24;
summat=0;
for row=rowst:1:rowend
for col=colst:1:colend
summat=summat+BW(row,col);
end
end
meanval=(summat)/(49*49);
meanmat(k,count)=meanval;
if(count>208)
count=1;k=k+1;
else
count=count+1;
end
end
end



% mean and median filter
I = im2double(BW);
kernel = ones(80,80) / (80*80); % 49*49 mean kernel
J = conv2(I, kernel, 'same'); % Convolve keeping size of I
stdDevImage = stdfilt(BW);
varianceIMage = stdDevImage .^2;
figure,subplot(2,2,1);
imshow(BW);title('Original');
subplot(2,2,2);
imshow(meanmat);title(sprintf('MeanImage'));
subplot(2,2,3);
imshow(varianceIMage);title(sprintf('variance using stdfilt'));
subplot(2,2,4);
imshow(J);title(sprintf('Average Variance using conv2'));
```

I have calculated mean,variance and average variance for the image using the above code.But the optic disc was not detected properly.Can anyone help me with the matlab code for finding the optic disc?

Comment: Probably, but can you post a picture that we can use to test, and define precisely what you mean by "optic disc"?

Answer (score 0):

```
%% Initial Image Processing.


% get image and mode from workspace
Im = evalin('base','Im');
singlemode = evalin('base','singlemode');

% apply filter on green component
f1 = fspecial('average',31); % create averaging filter
IMA = imadjust(Im(:,:,2)); % adjust green component intensity first
Imf = filter2(f1,IMA);  % apply filter
Imf = mat2gray(Imf); % convert back from (0,1) to (0,255)


axes(handles.axes2); % show grayscale filtered image
imshow(Imf);

%% Edge Detection.
thrsh = str2num(get(handles.edit1,'String')); % default = 0.98

Ibw=im2bw(Imf,thrsh); % binary mask / black & white threshold
I_edge = edge(Ibw);  % edge detection

% axes(handles.axes3);
% imshow(I_edge);      % show image


%% Circular Hough transform to detect optical disc (OD).

% Rmin = str2num(get(handles.edit3,'String')); % minimum radius from user input
% Rmax = str2num(get(handles.edit4,'String')); % maximum radius from user input

Rmin = 80;
Rmax = 120;

radii = Rmin:5:Rmax; % radii to check

h = circle_hough(I_edge,radii,'same','normalise');
peaks = circle_houghpeaks(h,radii,'nhoodxy',2*(Rmax/2)+1,'nhoodr',5,'npeaks',1); % find the peaks in the transform, meaning find the best fit of a circle. and we only want 1 circle.
%  Lines 196 -207 - if we're in single mode, we're plotting the circle in the top left image
if singlemode
    axes(handles.axes1);
    imshow(Im);
    hold on
    for peak = peaks
        [x y] = circlepoints(peak(3)); % This function returns the x,y coordinates of the found circle, peak(3) is the radius of the found circle.
        plot(x+peak(1),y+peak(2),'b-'); % we plot the x,y coordinates shifted by the center of the circle, which are peak(1) and peak(2)
    end

    plot(peak(1),peak(2),'r+'); % We plot the center of the circle with a red cross.
    hold off
end    
axes(handles.axes2); % Lines 208 - 214, we repeat the plot of the circle into axes2, the top right figure
hold on
for peak = peaks
    [x y] = circlepoints(peak(3));
    plot(x+peak(1),y+peak(2),'b-');
end
hold off


%% Region of Interest (ROI) Processing.
% we have localized the OD, define the ROI around this position for further
% processing.

axes(handles.axes2); % Activate axes2.
e = imellipse(gca,[peak(1)-2*peak(3) peak(2)-2*peak(3) 4*peak(3) 4*peak(3)]); %get an elliptical sub image centered around the peak(1) and peak(2) values (the centers of the previously found OD) and 2 times the radius that was found previously.
BW = createMask(e); %  Create a mask from this region of interest = ROI.

Imf_masked = Imf.*BW; % Apply mask to the image, this will make everything outside of the ROI become black.

% axes(handles.axes4);
% imshow(Imf_masked);

thrsh = str2num(get(handles.edit5,'String')); %  get threshold for ROI hough transform from the GUI, default = 0.65

Ibw=im2bw(Imf_masked,thrsh); % binary mask / black & white threshold (threshold the masked image).
I_edge = edge(Ibw);  % edge detection
% axes(handles.axes3);
% imshow(I_edge);      % show image

% hough transform to find circle in the ROI
h = circle_hough(I_edge,radii,'same','normalise');
peaks = circle_houghpeaks(h,radii,'nhoodxy',2*(Rmax/2)+1,'nhoodr',5,'npeaks',1);

if singlemode
    axes(handles.axes1);
    hold on
    for peak = peaks
        [x y] = circlepoints(peak(3));
        plot(x+peak(1),y+peak(2),'g-');
    end

    plot(peak(1),peak(2),'g+');
    hold off
end
```

Comment: Could you add a brief description of what your code is doing?